# Ethernet issues

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, ethernet, realtek

I can't get my RTL8111F Realtek ethernet embed chip to work like it should.I sincerely have no idea what to do now.

https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8111f

Symptoms:

1. It take too long sometimes to go up on boot. I have several gigabit cat6 cables. Same symptoms on all of them.Same symptoms connecting with other devices too.
2. Can get it to work above 100BaseTX - half-duplex.
3. Sometimes, when it goes up, the speed is too low. I can't get pass to ~2Mbps with internet speedtest tools. I even created a script to when that happens. Works like a charm, but it isn't a solution. Even so, it won't go above 100BaseTX - half-duplex.

The script basically drops down the interface, rise it up again and test the connection pinging some internet host, in this case, Google's DNS.

```
#!/bin/bash
re='^[0-9]+$'
while :
do
    ifconfig enp1s0 down && ifconfig enp1s0 up
    sleep 5 &&
    output_ping=$(ping -c 1 -W 0.4 8.8.8.8 | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -c47- | awk  '{ print $1 }' | sed -e 's/\.//g')

    if [[ $output_ping =~ $re ]]; then
        /usr/lib/anbox/anbox-bridge.sh restart
        break
    fi

done
```

My system is using r8169 drivers:

Output of `lspci -v`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the proprietary firmware matching your device.

See [this page](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) on realtek website or [this github repo](https://github.com/pop-os/linux-firmware/tree/master/rtl_nic)

Comment: I tried that already. I tested with r8168 and r8169 driver.